# C++ Static member function error C2556 overloaded function differs only by return type

Tags: c++, static

I want to write a static member function in my class CountInv, which should  have only this static function and no other members

//Inversions.h

```
#ifndef INV_H
#define INV_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class CountInv
{
    static void count();
}

#endif
```

//Inversions.cpp

```
#include "Inversions.h"

void CountInv::count() {    return; };
```

I get the following compiler error :

```
 Error  3   error C2556: 'CountInv CountInv::count(void)' : 
overloaded function differs only by return type 
from 'void CountInv::count(void)'   d:\...\inversions.cpp   4
```

What is wrong? Nowhere have I declared or defined 'CountInv CountInv::count(void)' !! Should I write class c-tors,..,d-tors, or maybe some static data members to return from this function? but this should not be the issue..

Comment: Have you saved the files before building? Are you building with the right files? In the right directory? Have you tried a clean rebuild?

Comment: Files are saved automatically. I've just cleaned and rebuilt solutions -- did not help.

Comment: add **;** to the end of class definition everything's goes fine!

Comment: I forgot the semicolon ; after the class definition in the header file.

Comment: Indeed Oleksandra: if only I knew how many hours I've wasted falling for that old chestnut. Note that Java does not require the `;` to close a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget the closing semicolon `;` after your class definition. That I think is causing the obscure compile error.

Comment: Yes it would do! Compilers find it difficult to detect this due to C++ grammar, so the compile errors you get are often very obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

add **;** to the end of class definition everything's goes fine!

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on my local visual studio and adding semicoln in Inversions.h after class definition solves problem.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi